# Disable the second, empty console labeled [Debug Console] when starting a debug target

Tags: eclipse

For reasons unclear, Eclipse has recently started bringing up two consoles every time I debug a project.  One console displays typical console information (stdout, stderr, etc.), and the other displays nothing. The titles are the same, except that the empty console is prefixed with "[Debug Console]". The empty one also comes up on top, which is quite inconvenient.

I haven't found anything useful in Eclipse's preferences or on Google. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Comment: And... a few days later Eclipse has mysteriously healed itself.  What made the difference?  Reopening Eclipse?  A restart?  The world may never know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, it did take me a while to figure out that not the logger was broken but Eclipse (Indigo / 3.7).

However, a simple *Eclipse* **restart** did helped me.

Comment: For historical note, Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) also has this.

Comment: Bug still present in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 (and presumably all previous versions as well)

Comment: And present in Mars 1 too.

Comment: Present in Mars 2, too.

Comment: Present in Neon Milestone 7, too.

Comment: Encountered this issue in the latest (as of now) **Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)**. Restarting Eclipse did help.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem is present in Eclipse Juno (3.8) as well. There is a ticket open in the Eclipse bugtracker [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355972), but it hasn't garnered any activity.

As mentioned in the ticket and by others here, restarting Eclipse seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

first you may try to remove your "workspace/.metadata" directory.
then restart eclipse.

Comment: Don't do that - it will trash your workspace. At most move somewhere, so you can move it back again.

Answer (score -3):

You need to re-enable the automatic console view.

Go to Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Console. Then check both:

+*Show when program writes to standard out*

+*Show when program writes to standard error*

Apply/OK.

(Works with Indigo/3.7)

Comment: This does not solves the problem. I want to disable "Debug Console". I don't want to re-enable those settings which I have disabled for my convinience.